# KQL. How can I make columns to show how many VM's connected every hour in a day?

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I have KQL that shows how many VM's connect in a time range. And shows Start time of connection, Stop time and Duration.
My code:

```
WVDConnections
| where SessionHostName contains "VM"
//| where UserName contains ""
| where State contains "Started"
| extend Started = TimeGenerated
| join kind= inner ( WVDConnections
    | where SessionHostName contains "VM"
    //| where UserName contains ""
    | where State contains_cs "Completed"
    | extend StopTime = TimeGenerated)
on CorrelationId
| extend Duration= StopTime - Started
| where Duration > 5m
| project Started, StopTime, SessionHostName, Duration
```

What I need is to show how many users was connected to some session host every hour, like it's shown in a picture. [image: Want to have something like that]
Is it possible to make it? Thanks for answers :)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: This question is not completely baked. **(1)** The number of open sessions can vary during an hour. What are you looking for, min / max / number on start/end of hour?  **(2)** Does this report spans over more than a day? Does it look on the last 24 hours and if so, I would you order the columns? Does it start on midnight and if so, is it UTC or local time? **(3)** What if a VM does not have connections at all in the examined period? Are you good with not displaying it?

Comment: Thanks for asking. 1) I need to know how many connections was at every hour of a day.
2) It can be more than a day. 3) If VM does not have connections at all at some hour then it can be 0

Comment: **(1)** As I said, there are multiple options here **(2)** In that case your required results should look differently, containing date and not only time **(3)** If you have no records for a VM, then you are not aware of its existence and you can't display anything for it, including 0s. You need a list of relevant VMs. It can be achieved by looking on the entire / part of the historical data.

Comment: This is trickier than seems at 1st sight, e.g., a scenario where100 sessions were opened 10 days ago and still running. If you look for events from the last day / week you get none, because nothing happened for the last day / week. You have no indication that you actually have open sessions.

Comment: User would be disconnected auto after not using it for some time. So max session time in this data that I get is near 24 hours but never more.

Comment: There is a good chance that you are misusing the *contains* operator. How do the actual values of `State` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's should do the trick.

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let _timeframeStart                 = 1d;
let _sessionsStartBeforeTimeframe   = 4h;
let _maxSessionDuration             = 12h;
let _vms                            = 7;
let _session                        = 100;
let WVDConnections = materialize
(
    range CorrelationId from 1 to _session step 1 
    | extend TimeGenerated      = ago((_timeframeStart + _sessionsStartBeforeTimeframe) * rand())
            ,SessionHostName    = strcat("VM", tostring(1 + toint(rand(_vms))))
    | mv-expand State           = dynamic(["Started", "Completed"]) to typeof(string)
               ,TimeGenerated   = pack_array(TimeGenerated, TimeGenerated + _maxSessionDuration * rand()) to typeof(datetime)
    | where TimeGenerated between (ago(_timeframeStart) .. now())
);
// Solution Starts here.
let t = materialize
(
    WVDConnections
    | where SessionHostName hasprefix "VM"
    | where State in ("Started", "Completed")
    | project TimeGenerated
             ,CorrelationId
             ,SessionHostName
             ,delta = iff(State == "Started", 1, -1)
);
let SessionsStartedPriorToTimeframe =
(
    t
    | summarize sum(delta) by CorrelationId, SessionHostName
    | summarize delta = countif(sum_delta == -1) by SessionHostName
    | where delta > 0 
);
let minTimeGenerated = toscalar(t | summarize min(TimeGenerated));
let maxTimeGenerated = toscalar(t | summarize max(TimeGenerated));
let VMsHoursProductJoin =
(
    range TimeGenerated from bin(minTimeGenerated, 1h) to maxTimeGenerated step 1h
    | extend dummy = 1
    | join kind=inner (t | distinct SessionHostName | extend dummy = 1) on dummy
);
union (t | project-away CorrelationId), (SessionsStartedPriorToTimeframe | extend TimeGenerated = minTimeGenerated)
| summarize hour_delta = sum(delta) by SessionHostName, bin(TimeGenerated, 1h)
| join kind=rightouter VMsHoursProductJoin on SessionHostName, TimeGenerated
| project SessionHostName   = SessionHostName1
         ,TimeGenerated     = TimeGenerated1
         ,hour_delta
| partition hint.strategy=native by SessionHostName
  (
    order by TimeGenerated asc
    | extend open_sessions = row_cumsum(hour_delta)
  )
| extend TimeGenerated_HH = format_datetime(TimeGenerated, "yyyy.MM.dd_HH")
| evaluate pivot(TimeGenerated_HH, take_any(open_sessions), SessionHostName)
| order by SessionHostName asc
```

| SessionHostName | 2022.11.23_18 | 2022.11.23_19 | 2022.11.23_20 | 2022.11.23_21 | 2022.11.23_22 | 2022.11.23_23 | 2022.11.24_00 | 2022.11.24_01 | 2022.11.24_02 | 2022.11.24_03 | 2022.11.24_04 | 2022.11.24_05 | 2022.11.24_06 | 2022.11.24_07 | 2022.11.24_08 | 2022.11.24_09 | 2022.11.24_10 | 2022.11.24_11 | 2022.11.24_12 | 2022.11.24_13 | 2022.11.24_14 | 2022.11.24_15 | 2022.11.24_16 | 2022.11.24_17 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VM1 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 7 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 6 |
| VM2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 7 | 6 | 6 | 9 | 7 | 6 | 6 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 2 |
| VM3 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 |
| VM4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| VM5 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| VM6 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| VM7 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=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)